# I need to remove the elements with repeated letters in the string

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, nested, break

```
String1 = “Python is an interpreted high level general purpose programming language”
List1 = String1.split()

for i in List1:
    for j in i:
        if i.count(j)>1:
            List1.remove(i)
            break
    
print(“ “.join(List1))
```

output:

> Python is an high general programming

Expected output:

> Python is an

Let me know the mistake I am making

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
String1 = "Python is an interpreted high level general purpose programming language"
List1 = String1.split()
ResultList = []

for i in List1:
    has_repeated_letter = False
    for j in i:
        if i.count(j) > 1:
            has_repeated_letter = True
            break
    if not has_repeated_letter:
        ResultList.append(i)

print(" ".join(ResultList))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex approach:

```py
inp = "Python is an interpreted high level general purpose programming language"
words = inp.split()
output = [x for x in words if not re.search(r'(\w)(?=.*\1)', x)]
print(output)  # ['Python', 'is', 'an']
```

The regex pattern used here will match any word for which any character occurs two or more times:

- `(\w)` match any single letter and capture in `\1`
- `(?=.*\1)` assert that this same character occurs later in the word

Answer (score 0):

One problem is [removing from a list while iterating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20delete,end%20index%20after%20each%20deletion.). It is almost always more useful to rebuild the list with the elements you *do* want:

```
List1 = [i for i in List1 if len(i) == len(set(i))]
# ['Python', 'is', 'an']
```

Turning the strings into sets removes duplicate letters. Hence the length comparison with the original string. You retain only those with only unique letters.